# Angular 5 - Importing Bootstrap 3 Carousel

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular, twitter-bootstrap

I have installed Bootstrap 3 and JQuery and is properly imported on my `.angular-cli.json` like so:

```
"styles": [
    "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
    ...some-other-css
],
"scripts": [
    "../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
    "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"
]
```

I've also implemented the basic Carousel by following [w3School's Bootstrap Carousel](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_ref_js_carousel.asp)

Moving forward, I was going to try altering a couple of things on my `app.component.js` such as the carousel's interval and etc.

With JQuery imported on my `app.component.js`, my `ngOnInit()` would look something like:

```
ngOnInit() {
    $('.carousel').carousel({
        interval: 500
    });
}
```

Which returns an error that says:
`ERROR TypeError: $(...).carousel is not a function`

***Things that I tried***:

- Importing bootstraps `carousel.js` into the scripts like so:

`"scripts": [
    "../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
    "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js",
    "../node_modules/bootstrap/js/carousel.js"
]`

- Used `ngx-bootstrap` (An Angular's wrapper for Bootstrap). But I don't think this one fits my requirement and is not as customizable